# If you can get shocked by current through the earth, why don't we use the earth as a conductor in our power circuit?

Tags: ground

I am not sure about that..i only know it uses as a return circuit.

Comment: How can you "get shocked by current through earth" ?

Comment: "Earth" is just the path the current takes, you still need a current source...

Comment: @EugeneSh. oh, you can.  Lightning regularly kills 4-legged animals.  The strike causes a voltage gradient across the ground, and the animal's front legs wind up several hundred volts above their hind legs.  Current takes all available paths in proportion to their conductance (1/resistance), *so*...  The same thing will happen to you if you stand spread-legged near the lightning strike.

Answer (score 4):

[You can use single wire earth return (SWER) as an AC distribution system.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-wire_earth_return)

As you can see from the wikipedia site, power can be distributed using the earth as the second connection to close the circuit.

It is used in rural areas to make the power lines cheaper  - just one wire to run.

The downside is that you are depending on the random and changing characteristics of the ground.  "Random" because no two stretches of dirt are the same, and changing because the resistance of the ground changes depending on the weather (rain.)

The varying resistance of the dirt means your voltage varies with the weather, and probaby the amount of power you can draw.